# Doctrine 2: Cannot associate an existing entity object with a new entity object

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm having a bit of trouble with `Doctrine 2` - I have a pre-existing entity called `Site` with data (i.e. a table with some rows) which has a `oneToMany` relationship with an entity called `User`.

My `User` entity has a `manyToOne` relationship with `Site`.

When creating a new user entity, I would like to link it to a specific site.  My code is as follows:

```
// create entity manager instance
$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connection, $config);

// get the site ID entry i'd like to insert into this user
$site = $em->createQuery('SELECT s FROM Entity\Site s WHERE s.name = ?1')->setParameter(1, 'My Site')->getResult();

// create new user
$obj = new \Entity\User;

// associate user with site
$obj->setJoiningSite($site[0]);

$em->persist($obj);
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

Now my issue: running this code snippet multiple times results in the creation of a new site entity for each new user entity, i.e. it's not using the single existing site, but creating a new one each time.

Here are the relevant parts of my `YAML` file.  First Site:

```
Entity\Site:
    type: entity
    table: sites
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 100
    oneToMany:
        users:
            targetEntity: Entity\User
            mappedBy: site
```

And here is `User`:

```
Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: users
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: 20
    manyToOne:
        joining_site:
            targetEntity: Entity\Site
            mappedBy: users
            cascade: ["persist"]
            joinColumn:
                name: join_site_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Why is it doing this and how can I get the behaviour I'm looking for?

Thanks

Comment: how you implement your setJoiningSite method?

Comment: I just updated my question with the YAML files used to generate the entities (and the setJoiningsite() method)

Comment: mappedBy: users<- Should be the attribute name in your entity class User used to map it. Set it to mappedBy: joinSite if you use $joinSite as the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$site = $em->getRepository('Entity\User')->findOneBy(array('name' => [name_of_site]));
$user = new Entity\User();
$user->setJoiningSite($site);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

and your method like this:

```
public function setJoiningSite($site) {
    $this->site = $site;
}
```

You must to declare the site property as Entity\Site class.

Comment: Just figured this out.  Thanks for the feedback Guido - turned out that I just needed the reference to the entity, rather than the entity itself. Here is the code (SO comment formatting is bullshit): https://gist.github.com/exnor/6011197